# using usort to re-arrange multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, json, usort

I have a large array (this is just a section of it):

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [products] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [body_html] => bodyhtml
                        [published_at] => 2012-12-16T23:59:18+00:00
                        [created_at] => 2012-12-16T11:30:24+00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2012-12-18T10:52:14+00:00
                        [vendor] => Name
                        [product_type] => type
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [body_html] => bodyhtml
                        [published_at] => 2012-12-16T23:59:18+00:00
                        [created_at] => 2012-12-16T10:30:24+00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2012-12-18T10:52:14+00:00
                        [vendor] => Name
                        [product_type] => type
                    )
              )
      )
```

and I need to arrange each of the products by the date they where created... 
I've tried and failed all kinds of usort, ksort, uksort techniques to try and get it to be in a specific order (chronological) but failed!

any guidance would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the uasort function, which lets you specify a simple comparison function you write.  See [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) for specifics. You can also define an anonymous function as part of the uasort call.  Since you have an object with an array, make sure that you are passing the object's array to the uasort function.  Since you're sorting an array of objects, your comparison function should take into account that it's working with 2 objects.

Building upon your responses and your var_dump:

```
uasort($foo[0]->products, function($a, $b) {

    if ($a->created_at < $b->created_at) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: That's where I'm getting lost, I can do it to a single array but going deeper into the array is where I fail...

Comment: "I can do it to a single array but going deeper into the array is where I fail."  Give us a little help here.  I do not see anything but one array of objects.  It happens to be inside an object, but that should not prevent sorting.  Am I missing something?  Thanks, ~Ray

Comment: I'm struggling with the array within the array and getting the created_at data out of that second array and then organising all of the products using that...

Comment: I updated my response.  $foo in my example should be whatever variable you var_dump'd above.

Comment: Hurrah that's worked! Thank you so much gview, apologies for my descriptions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$arr_1 = array('name' => 'A', 
               'date' => '2012-12-16T11:30:24+00:00' , 
               'created_at' => '2012-12-16T11:30:24+00:00');
$arr_2 = array('name' => 'B', 
               'date' => '2012-12-16T11:30:22+00:00' , 
               'created_at' => '2012-12-16T11:30:21+00:00');


$test_array = array($arr_1, $arr_2);
var_dump($test_array);

usort($test_array, function($a, $b) {
    $a_date = new DateTime($a['date']);
    $b_date = new DateTime($b['date']);
    if ($a_date < $b_date) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});

var_dump($test_array);
```

Comment: The date format actually is formatted that it can be compared like a string, with the earlier dates being the "smaller" strings. There is no need to parse them with DateTime.

Comment: @Sven ok. I see, that's not what his problem is. It's the multi dimensional aspect that he's having problems with.